# restore / reset an indvidual hunk in my worktree from magit?

Tags: magit

In magit, I can stage or unstage a single hunk (or even parts of a hunk). So those are operations on the index / staging area.

How can I do the corresponding thing but on my working tree?

For example, say I added a one-off comment to myself in some code while debugging. I'm committing the fix -- but I don't want to commit that comment, and in fact since I've fixed the bug, I want to remove it from my working tree, too.

From the command line, `git restore --patch <file>` does this.

In magit, `X` (for `reset`) does that at the level of an entire file.

I want to connect these two things and get hunk-level behavior for magit's `reset`. Does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“k” to discard hunks or even all changes to a file.

Comment: That's exactly it! The only teeny-tiny thing is that I might want `k`, when used on a *staged* hunk, to just unstage it but it discards it entirely and reverts the buffer.

Comment: If you want to unstage it, then use `u` instead. It’s no good trying to have one command that reads the user’s mind and does both.

Comment: I'm surprised at how many things in emacs do indeed seem to read my mind. There's the whole "dwim" concept, which...does what I mean. :)  

But, yes, `u` does unstage the hunk.